# Creating a new login form in react js with mvc but the jsx part is not rendering

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs

I am trying to Create a new login form in react js with mvc but the jsx part is not rendering.

index.cshtml

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper" id="signup"></div>
    <link href="Assets/Css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Assets/Js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Assets/JS/react.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Assets/JS/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Assets/JS/remarkable.min.js"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Assets/JS/login.jsx")"></script> 
</body>
```

below body section also js,bootstrap and materialkit.js file is there.

login.JSX

```
class NameForm extends React.Component {
 render() {
    return (
         <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
           .........
         </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<NameForm/>,document.getElementById('signup'));
```

but after excecuting the part inside login.jsx is not rendering 
The property define in the head section in index.cshtml file

```
<style type="text/css">
        body {
            background-image: url('Assets/Img/bg2.jpg');
            background-size: cover; /* <------ */
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center center; /* optional, center the image */
        }
    </style>
```

render the image only.Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: @ADyson this is the error:MsieJavaScriptEngine.JsRt.Edge.EdgeJsScriptException: Script threw an exception.